# Deployment failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

I am having two cluster `cluster-1` and `cluster-2`.

In `cluster-1` deployed `service-1` in the namespace `test-namespace-1`. It got deployed successfully and running.

In `cluster-2` deployed `service-1` in the namespace `test-namespace-1`. Deployment status showing error as `HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500`

When I checked the details, it has two `conditions`

1. `Processing` status as `true`
2. `Available` status as `false` and reason is `MinimumreplicaUnavailable`

I checked both namespaces quota details.

- limits.cpu - used:43 hard:90
- limits.memory - used:65000Mi hard:96Gi
- persistencevolumeclaims - used:8 hard:10
- pods - used:35 hard:65

other details like request's storage, cpu etc have almost 40% available but in one clsuetr's namespace it is showing success and running and in another cluaster's namespace failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got fixed, actual issue is due to `deployment.yml` file, liveness and readyness probes are mapped to `8090` but start probe was mapped to `8080` by the team. Due to this deployment got failed.

Answer (score 1):

Check your container log and pod's event log.

`HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500` means your application did not start successfully or returns error in the healthcheck path (liveness/readiness probe) or the initial delay too early for your app to start.

If it's the liveness/readiness probe problem, it is a good idea to also set up the liveness/readiness probe config. See [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/)

`MinimumreplicaUnavailable` means your pod did not scale successfully as intended. If it was scheduling problem (inefficient resources), you should get another error saying "insufficient...." instead.

Comment: deployment doesn't have any issue with pods scaling, it got scaled up and two pods got created.